# How do I create dynamic constraints in Matlab

Tags: matlab, optimization, dynamic, constraints

I'm trying to solve an optimization problem with dynamic constraints. This is basically creating a vehicle trajectory. The last three lines explain multiple constraints by states of each step.
I want to create these three lines using for loop. How can I do this?
`eval([ '...' num2str(i)]) = equation;` doesn't work.

code is as following:

```
%% MILP
% create opt.problem (max.)
prob = optimproblem('ObjectiveSense','maximize');

% creat variables
x = optimvar('x', sim_time_opt, 'lowerbound', 0);

% set objective function (last location)
prob.Objective = x(sim_time_opt,1);

% set constraints
% vmax
prob.Constraints.cons1 = ((x(1,1)-x0)/dt <= vmax);
prob.Constraints.cons2 = ((x(2,1) - x(1,1)) / dt <= vmax);
prob.Constraints.cons3 = ((x(3,1) - x(2,1)) / dt <= vmax);
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to use a loop there? What is wrong with the code as written?

Comment: @CrisLuengo because I need to create tons of constraints :)

Comment: How do you plan generate the constraints themselves, though?

Answer (score 0):

In MATLAB, this:

```
prob.Constraints.cons1 = ((x(1,1)-x0)/dt <= vmax);
```

is the same as this:

```
name = 'cons1';
prob.Constraints.(name) = ((x(1,1)-x0)/dt <= vmax);
```

The variable `name` can be created, for example, using `sprintf`:

```
name = sprintf('cons%d',index);
```

(Of course `index` is the number of the constraint, maybe the loop index.)

I don’t know how you want to generate the constraints, but you should try to avoid `eval`, as it is a security hazard and very inefficient.

Comment: Can I generate multiple names with loop using this?

Comment: @seunghanryu: I’ve added that to the answer.